# How to use ReadAllText when file encoding unknown

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

Im reading a file with **ReadAllText**

```
    String[] values = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\\c\\file.txt").Split(';');

    int i = 0;

    foreach (String s in values)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("output: {0} {1} ", i, s);
        i++;
    }
```

If I try to read some files I get sometimes the the wrong character back (for ÖÜÄÀ...). The output is like '?', its because there is some trouble with the encoding:

```
output: 0 TEST
output: 1 A??O?
```

One solution would be to set the encoding in ReadAllText, lets say something like `ReadAllText(@"c:\\c\\file.txt", Encoding.UTF8)` that could fix the problem. But what if I would still get '?' as output? What if I dont know the encoding of the file? And what if every single file got a different encoding? What would be the best way to do it with c#? Thank you

Comment: You need to know what the encoding is. And there is no 100% reliable way to find out based purely on the contents of the file.

Comment: Please refer to this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239968/c-sharp-file-readalltext-doing-weird-things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to reliably do this is to look for [byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) at the start of the text file. (This blob more generally represents the endianness of character encoding used, but also the encoding - e.g. UTF8, UTF16, UTF32). Unfortunately, this method only works for Unicode-based encodings, and nothing before that (for which much less reliable methods must be used).

The [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) type supports detecting these marks to determine the encoding - you simply need to pass a flag to the parameter as such:

```
new System.IO.StreamReader("path", true)
```

You can then check the value of `stremReader.CurrentEncoding` to determine the encoding used by the file. Note however that if no byte encoding marks exist, then `CurrentEncoding` will default to `Encoding.Default`.

[Refer codeproject solution to detect encoding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17201/Detect-Encoding-for-In-and-Outgoing-Text)

Comment: If no byte encoding marks exist, then CurrentEncoding will use Encoding.UTF8 **not** Encoding.Default. "The detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks parameter detects the encoding by looking at the first three bytes of the stream. It automatically recognizes UTF-8, little-endian Unicode, and big-endian Unicode text if the file starts with the appropriate byte order marks. Otherwise, the UTF8Encoding is used." [from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y86s1a9.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You have to check file encoding first. try this

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = null; 
System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read); 
if (file.CanSeek) 
{ 
    byte[] bom = new byte[4]; // Get the byte-order mark, if there is one 
    file.Read(bom, 0, 4); 
    if ((bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) || // utf-8 
        (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) || // ucs-2le, ucs-4le, and ucs-16le 
        (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) || // utf-16 and ucs-2 
        (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff)) // ucs-4 
    { 
        enc = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; 
    } 

    // Now reposition the file cursor back to the start of the file 
    file.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin); 
} 
else 
{ 
    // The file cannot be randomly accessed, so you need to decide what to set the default to 
    // based on the data provided. If you're expecting data from a lot of older applications, 
    // default your encoding to Encoding.ASCII. If you're expecting data from a lot of newer 
    // applications, default your encoding to Encoding.Unicode. Also, since binary files are 
    // single byte-based, so you will want to use Encoding.ASCII, even though you'll probably 
    // never need to use the encoding then since the Encoding classes are really meant to get 
    // strings from the byte array that is the file. 

    enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that the FileStream is open after this code and should be closed if this code is used in some `GetEncoding` method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating some simple json file and was getting same error.
The problem was creating the file using Visual Studio (2019 at the moment).

I am sure you can find some configuration in VS options to deal with this issue. However, the quickiest way I've found was to create the same file and content using Notepad++.
You can set the encoding in Notepad++ by visiting Encoding top menu.
And I believe you may also find similar config in other text editors.