# Invalid characters in File.ReadAllText

Tags: c#, text, character-encoding, special-characters, symbols

I'm calling `File.ReadAllText()` in a program designed to format some files that I have.

Some of these files contain the `®` (174) symbol. However, when the text is being read, the returned string contains `�` (65533) symbols where the `®` (174) should be.

What would cause this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is likely due to a mismatch in the `Encoding`.  Use the [ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) overload which allows you to specify the proper `Encoding` to use when reading the file.

The default overload will assume UTF-8 unless it can detect UTF-32.  Any other encoding will come through incorrectly.

Comment: Is there a reason that the method doesn't use Encoding.Default as it's default encoding?

Comment: @mrK Not sure why it's that way, but that's what the framework designer's chose to use.  It's documented, but I agree, an odd choice.

Comment: One explanation could be that `Encoding.Default` uses the so-called  current ANSI code page of the system which varies from system to system. Using UTF-8 avoids encoding errors you get from encoding and decoding on systems with different current ANSI code pages. Furthermore UTF-8 can encode all of UNICODE.

Answer (score 15):

Most likely the file contains a different encoding than the default.  If you know it, you can specify it using the [File.ReadAllText Method (String, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) override.

Code sample:

```
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default);  // <-- change the encoding to whatever the encoding really is
```

If you ***DON'T*** know the encoding, see this previous SO question: [How to use ReadAllText when file encoding unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753417/how-to-use-readalltext-when-file-encoding-unknown)

Comment: Encoding.Default no longer works in .NET Core, always returns utf8...

Answer (score 14):

You need to specify the encoding when you call [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx), unless the file is actually in UTF-8, which it sounds like it's not. (Basically the one-parameter overload is equivalent to passing in UTF-8 as the second argument. It will also detect UTF-32 with an appropriate byte-order mark, I believe.)

The first thing is to work out which encoding it *is* in (e.g. ISO-8859-1 - but you need to *check* this) and then pass that as a second argument.

For example:

```
Encoding isoLatin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
string text = File.ReadAllText(path, isoLatin1);
```

It's *always* important that you know what encoding binary data is using before you try to read it as text. That's true for files, network streams, anything.

Answer (score 0):

The character you are reading is the Replacement character

> used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode
>   compare the use of U+001A as a control character to indicate the substitute function

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

You are getting this because the actual encoding of the file does not match the encoding your program expects.

By default ReadAllText expects UTF-8.  It is encountering a byte sequence that does not represent a valid UTF-8 character, so replacing it with the *Replacement character*.